# Why is extension of degree $2$ always _Galois_ $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

$E$  is  any  arbitrary  field  with  char$\neq 2$ . And $F$  is  an  extension of  $E$  such  that  $[E:F]=2$ .  Then $E/F$  is  *Galois*  extension .

Since  the  degree  is  $2$ ,  the  irreducible  polynomial  of  any  element  of  $E$  is  quadratic *:*  $$ax^{2}+bx+c$$

Now  giving  $x$  a  translation  by  $\ \ ({-}{{a}\over {2}})\ \ $  reduces  the  polynomial  to  the  form _:_$$x^{2}-d$$

So  $d$  and  $-d$  are  two  roots  of the  polynomial  and   it  splits  over  $E$.  Hence  $E/F$  is  *Galois* .

But  nowhere  in  the  proof    did  I   use  the  fact  that $char(F)\neq 2$ 
or   the  concept   of   *characteristic*  of  fields  at  all  .  Then  is  the  proof  correct  $?$ .

If  so  then  why  do  we  have  to  mention  that  *char*($F$)$\neq2$ $?$  What  purpose  does  it  serve $?$

I  really  need  clarification  on  this  part .

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: You divided by $2$!

Comment: I think you wrote your polynomial wrong: your proof works for the polynomial $X^2+aX+b$.

Answer (score 0):

In characteristic $2$, there are two possibilities for an irreducible quadratic $X^2+aX+b$. If $a=0$, then the extension is inseparable, and thus non-Galois. If $a\ne0$, then the extension is separable, and Galois, ’cause if $z$ is one root, the other root is $a+z$, so your factorization over $k(a)$ is $(X+z)(X+a+z)$.